# How do I center a table to one half of an A5 page when setting up and printing on A4?

Tags: tables, spacing

I'd like to print 2 identical tables on either side of a landscape a4 page. At the moment, they both print slightly too near the center fold (about 8mm from center fold, but then 23mm from the other edge of the paper). This is my first time using anything that even resembles code, I've somehow managed to get this far but I have no idea how to change it and google isn't helping this time. Any ideas what I need to add or change? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1.5cm, bmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
 \title{Index}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption* {Index}
        \begin{tabular}{| M{1.5cm}| M{ 3.5cm }|M{1.5cm}| M{3.5cm}|}
        \hline
            Pages & Content & Pages & Content \\
        \hline
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption* {Index}
        \begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{3.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{3.5cm}|}
        \hline
            Pages & Content & Pages & Content \\
        \hline
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking here.  (Welcome to TeX.SE, by the way, and thanks for providing a MWE!)  Are you printing a booklet, and you want the identical table on both sides of a single spread?

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm doing, my brain just couldn't work out how to put it into words.

Answer (score 1):

The `\centering` instructions inside the `minipage` environments are messing up your layout. Use `\raggedright` in the first minipage and `\raggedleft` in the second. Also, terminate the first `minipage` with a `%` (comment character) in order to have no gap (in the amount of a space) between the two minipages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
 %%\title{Index}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      %%\centering
      \raggedright
      \caption* {Index}
        \begin{tabular}{| M{1.5cm}| M{ 3.5cm }|M{1.5cm}| M{3.5cm}|}
        \hline
            Pages & Content & Pages & Content \\
        \hline
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%  % <--- note the comment character
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
      %%\centering
      \raggedleft
      \caption* {Index}
        \begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{3.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{3.5cm}|}
        \hline
            Pages & Content & Pages & Content \\
        \hline
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        & & & \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! Now that I've done that though, it hasn't affected the 'Index' title thing. Is there a way to make that center with the table?

Comment: @RobynLJF - Your code didn't feature a `\maketitle` instruction, so I couldn't tell if you wanted a title on that page. If you add `\maketitle` (and, probably, `\date}{`) after `\title`, you'll get a centered title.,